# How to query LocalDateTime columns annotated by @CreatedDate or @LastModifiedDate in JPA or Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I use JPA auditing on my Entity class and I want to query the Entity class by QueryDSL, JPQL, query method of JPA or whatever.

like:

- QueryDSL: .where(qBattery.updateDate.after(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(10L)))
- JPQL: where b.updateDate >= :localDateTime
- List findAllByUpdateDateGreaterThanEqual(LocalDateTime localDateTime);

But, None of the above ways worked.

Should I add some configs on the AuditorAware or Is there another way?

I use hibernate 5.4.32 final
so I think I don't need to use AttributeConverter, hibernate-java8, Jsr310JpaConverters.

Any answers would be helpful.

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by "None of the above ways worked"? Do you receive an error? Which one? Do you get an empty result? Could you confirm that columns are populated in the DB (have non-null values)?

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is exactly the wrong type to use for tracking moments, specific points in time. That type lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. Instead, use `OffsetDateTime` to exchange a moment with a database column whose type should be akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

Comment: @IllyaKysil The meaning is all of three ways get an empty result and that columns are populated. Additionally, the type of columns are java.time.LocalDateTime.

Comment: @BasilBourque I appreciate for your comment. But, I get some errors like "Supported types are [org.joda.time.DateTime, org.joda.time.LocalDateTime, java.util.Date, java.lang.Long, long]" when I apply OffsetDateTime to JPA Audit.

Comment: Note the end of my comment. Your database column may be the wrong type, a type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. For tracking moments, as with an audit trail, you *must* be using a column type akin to SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. On the Java side, three types can represent a moment, `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, and `ZonedDateTime`. Of those, `OffsetDateTime` is meant for exchanging values to that SQL type.